# Add a style to a table in `Graphics[Point[{...}]]`

Tags: graphics, list-manipulation, style

I want to create a graphic of a series of points. It's easy as long as I don't want to style the points:

```
Module[{z = 1 + I},
 table1 = Table[{Re[((z^2 + 1)/(z^2 - 1))^k], Im[((z^2 + 1)/(z^2 - 1))^k]}, {k, 1, 25, 2}]; 
 Graphics[Point[table1]]
]
```

But when I try to add a `Darker[Red]` style to the points, it stops working:

```
Module[{z = 1 + I},
 table1 = Table[{Re[((z^2 + 1)/(z^2 - 1))^k], Im[((z^2 + 1)/(z^2 - 1))^k]}, {k, 1, 25, 2}]; 
 Graphics[Point[{Darker[Red], table1}]]
]
```

I am sure that someone will suggest using `ComplexListPlot`, but my question is not about using `ComplexListPlot`, it's about how to do this using `Graphics[Point[{...}]]`. All I am after is a quick and dirty check of the geometry, and `Point` delivers that - only apparently without the style!

I am using Mathematica 12.1.1.0 for MacOS.

Comment: try `Graphics[{Darker[Red], Point[ table1]}]`?

Comment: Hi @kglr. Thank you - thought I'd tried that, obviously hadn't! It works. Do you want to put it up as an answer for me to tick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the styling directive before `Point`:

```
Graphics[{Darker[Red], Point[table1]}]
```

or wrap `Point[...]` with `Style`:

```
Graphics[Style[Point[table1], Darker[Red]]]
```

to get

[image]